# Is there sandbox environment available for Twitter development?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I've found only Ads API Sandbox on Twitter dev pages but this doesn't serve my purpose. I'm also aware that I can create separate account just for testing but would like to know if this can be avoided.

Concious this question was asked around 5 years ago and the answer was NO but would like to know if anyone is aware of any changes in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Twitter does not have a playground / sandbox for API testing except for the Ads API.

Comment: Out of curiosity - no commitment - what would you expect / want that to look like and work like?

Comment: From my perspective (working on little automation currently) - key features: 1. test user creation that could interact with your app 
2. dev mode - nobody can see what you post except for the test users